# Problem Internal Transaction Ethereum ( Funds dont appear in my wallet)

Tags: go-ethereum

I have some funds frozen in ‘internal transactions’ and dont appear in my wallet ethereum.

I sended ethereum with exchangue “Buddha” to my wallet, and them work sending ethereum with smart contracts but i see that wallet Blockchain dont support it.

My wallet Ethereum is this:

0xA8C74d91114C9971866ad4063B922C8cEE45cCC5
[image]

I offer 1 ethereum who can help me solve it

https://www.blockchain.com/eth/address/0xa8c74d91114c9971866ad4063b922c8cee45ccc5?view=internal

Answer (score 1):

Internal transactions don't appear in the normal transaction history, because technically they aren't transactions. Internal transactions are initialised by another transaction, sent to a smart contract. That smart contract then sends funds to your address.

The internal transaction was [sent 10 days ago](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2a1b4befcc93d8675626c29bd47bfa87455e44be9121dc7694b6c7bf07d4c63b), and most of the funds were transferred out again in [this transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8738b31f9a71f6b7ca00038e09c334837491a7623640dcec5796ca66e2e2cc83). Your Ether isn't stuck, most of it is just sent out already.

Comment: I have some payments, in totally are 39 transactions in internal transaction that i didnt received yet,.

Comment: How i can get these funds? Because, if i check my wallet never appear these funds

Comment: Funds sent in an internal transaction are automatically added to your balance, you don't need to do anything. Most Ether that you received is already sent to other addresses.